# How to define function inside onMouseOver and onMouseOut

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div align="right" style="border:1 #FF0 solid; background-color:#999" onMouseOver="javascript: function(){this.style.backgroundColor = '#DDD';}" onMouseOut="javascript: function(){this.style.backgroundColor = '#999';}">
Register
</div>
```

When mouseover event triggered it gives this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token (

What should I do? I want to define a function inside `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `function` declaration, just do:

```
onMouseOver = "this.style.backgroundColor = '#DDD';"
```

And:

```
onMouseOut = "this.style.backgroundColor = '#999';"
```

By the way, you should consider ***[unobstrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)***.

Comment: I know but I just wanted to try something different :) and this looks like more efficient than calling a function ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want a function in your scenario? You could just use..

onMouseOut="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor = '#999'">

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look at jQuery and using unobtrusive javascript.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That is all you need, it will pull the jQuery library off of Google.

Then you can have an external stylesheet to handle what you want to do.

```
<div id="container"> Register </div>
```

THen you need to create an external stylesheet such as app.css:

```
#container {border:1 #FF0 solid; background-color:#999;text-align:left;}
```

And then you can have an external script such as app.js

```
$('#container').mouseout(function() {
  $('#container').css('backgroundColor', '#DDD')
});
```

Don't forget to link the external css and js to the the page. The external stylesheet needs to be linked to after the jQuery script.

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
```

You can edit the script to add more functions when the mouse does stuff:

```
$('#container').mouseout($('#container').css('backgroundColor', '#DDD'))
$('#container').mouseover($('#container').css('backgroundColor', '#DDD'))
$('#container').mouseenter($('#container').css('backgroundColor', '#DDD'))
$('#container').mouseup($('#container').css('backgroundColor', '#DDD'))
```

There is a whole slew of theme here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use css?

## element:hover(){

}

or is it the js function you need and the bg is just an example?... in this case you can get an easy result with jQuery
$("#element").mouseover(function(){
$(this).addClass("bghover");
});

$("#element").mouseoutfunction(){
$(this).removeClass("bghover");
});

Answer (score 0):

You can define external javascript method, which accepts the required argument, and use this method for several  elements:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function OnMouseDownEventHandler(sender) {
    sender.style.backgroundColor = '#DDD';
}
</script>

<div onmousedown="OnMouseDownEventHandler(this);"></div>
```

Comment: No, I don't want to call a function